# Adding existing item to Cart (React-Redux)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm using React and Redux for creating shop. I need to add existing item to cart with increasing quantity.
I know, that Redux is based on immutability, but I can't find how to get rid of mutation. Please, give me a hint.
So, there is my code

Actions:

```js
export const UPDATE_QTY = 'UPDATE_QTY';
export const UPDATE_CART = 'UPDATE_CART';
```

Reducer and initialState:

```js
    const initialState = {
     cart: [],
     qty: 0,
     total: 0,
     delivery: 5,
     };

export const cartReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.UPDATE_QTY:
      let existedItem = state.cart.filter((cartItem) => cartItem.id === action.payload.id);
      existedItem[0].qty = action.payload.qty;
      return {
        ...state,
        qty // how to get rid of mutation here?
      };
    case actions.UPDATE_CART:
      return { ...state, cart:[...state.cart, action.payload] };
    default:
      return state;
     }
    };
```

And my Component with dispatch:

```js
export default function AddBtn({ id }) {
  const itemData = useSelector((state) => state.main.items);
  const cartData = useSelector((state) => state.app.cart);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleAddToCart = () => {
    const addedItem = itemData.find((item) => item.id === id);
    const existedItem = cartData.find((item) => id === item.id);

    if (existedItem) {
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_QTY,
        payload: { id, qty: existedItem.qty + 1 },
      });
    } else {
      dispatch({
        type: UPDATE_CART,
        payload: addedItem,
      });
    }
return (
// JSX code
)
```

Comment: Well, for calculating qty I used another action

Comment: why is qty outside of cart array object?should that array hold items that have qty property?

Comment: Apostolos, well, maybe I need to think about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use map function instead, which are `immutable`:

```
const initialState = {
  cart: [],
  qty: 0,
  total: 0,
  delivery: 5,
};

export const cartReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.UPDATE_QTY:
      return {
        ...state,
        cart: state.cart.map(el => {
          if (el.id === action.payload.id) {
            return {
              ...el,
              qty: action.payload.qty
            }
          }

          return el;
        })
      };
    case actions.UPDATE_CART:
      return { ...state,
        cart: [...state.cart, action.payload]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
     const initialState = {
         cart: [],
         qty: 0,
         total: 0,
         delivery: 5,
         };
    
    export const cartReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case actions.UPDATE_QTY:
          let existedItem = state.cart.find((cartItem) => cartItem.id === action.payload.id);
if(existedItem){
 existedItem.qty = action.payload.qty;
}
         
          return {
            ...state,
            cart:[...state.cart] // how to get rid of mutation here?
          };
        case actions.UPDATE_CART:
          return { ...state, cart:[...state.cart, action.payload] };
        default:
          return state;
         }
        };
```